# /dev/console missing when mounting nfs

Tags: nfs, root-filesystem

I'm trying to boot linux on a remote device.
I load a uImage of the kernel via tftp:

```
boot -uboot -tftp TFTP_SERVER:uImage
```

and tell him where to find the root fs:

```
console=ttyS0,9600 ip= {IPs here} root=/dev/nfs nfsroot={ROOTFS_SERVER}:/{PATH_TO_MOUNT},nfsvers=3,tcp
```

and I get:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: /dev/console is missing or not a character device!
Please ensure your rootfs is properly configured
```

I'm using CFE bootloader. 
What is the meaning of this error? I tried looking online but didn't find any explanation.

Comment: i mean it seems quite simple to me. if you want to use this legacy initrd-free method, then you must include `/dev` with the minimally required device nodes.

Comment: kernel opens the console node to provide the stdin/stdout/stderr for init